# Ephesoft: tesseract isn't working

Tags: tesseract, ephesoft

I'm trying to learn files but for some reason or another, some pdf's that come from exactly the same scanner, and are visually of similar quality don't work.

I don't get an error, everything works but it's just that it isn't abble to actyually ocr anything. the ocr file is just empty. it's like the Tesseract isn't abble to find any words on it.

Comment: I have not the solution, but dealing with the same issues I came here: http://wiki.ephesoft.com/recommended-settings-for-better-ocr-results

Comment: My scanner automatically swichs from black and white to color depending on the document, so I am testing the results changing from one to another in an static scan mode.